# Wait state: Statistics

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, statistics, wait-types, mariadb-10.5

We have 200 databases in one instance of MariaDB with a total of 370.000 tables, since we upgraded to MariaDB 10.5.11, we see most of time passed by mysql is in wait states: Statistics.

According MariaDB, it should be a brief state:
Calculating statistics as part of deciding on a query execution plan. Usually a brief state unless the server is disk-bound.
But we don't see particular high usage of the disk.

Trying to help this situation, we generated all Engine-Independent Table Statistics by analyzing all tables(370.000), our use_stat_tables is set to preferably_for_queries to use those stats instead of innodb one's. No real improvement.

We also tried to switch optimizer_search_depth to 0, no improvement either.

And another consequence of this huge time passed calculating statistics, it increased by a lot our daily backup time with mysqldump of the 200 databases (before 30 min, now around 5 hours!) which crashes the server most of time, because the memory increased after each database backup, until the server swap.

Some more details, after 11 hours running

With mariadb 10.1 - 2 weeks
[image: Statistics in Mariadb 10.1 for 2 weeks are really low]

With MariaDB 10.5 - 2 weeks
[image: Statistics in Mariadb 10.5 for 2 weeks]

We just received some advice to increase the open-files-limit, we still have to do it in production, and then raise table_open_cache (for now it's table_open_cache = 20000, table_definition-cache = 40000)
Now max open files for mariadb is set to 32768:

```
cat /proc/$(pidof mariadbd)/limits
Limit Soft Limit Hard Limit Units
Max cpu time unlimited unlimited seconds
Max file size unlimited unlimited bytes
Max data size unlimited unlimited bytes
Max stack size 8388608 unlimited bytes
Max core file size 0 unlimited bytes
Max resident set unlimited unlimited bytes
Max processes 160172 160172 processes
Max open files 32768 32768 files
Max locked memory 65536 65536 bytes
Max address space unlimited unlimited bytes
Max file locks unlimited unlimited locks
Max pending signals 160172 160172 signals
Max msgqueue size 819200 819200 bytes
Max nice priority 0 0
Max realtime priority 0 0
Max realtime timeout unlimited unlimited us
```

We are running out of ideas.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is the output of 'show global status'

```
| Aborted_clients                                        | 613                                              |
| Aborted_connects                                       | 1                                                |
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_not_flushed                      | 0                                                |
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_unused                           | 4                                                |
| Aria_pagecache_blocks_used                             | 15647                                            |
| Aria_pagecache_read_requests                           | 23111163                                         |
| Aria_pagecache_reads                                   | 190134                                           |
| Aria_pagecache_write_requests                          | 1085362                                          |
| Aria_pagecache_writes                                  | 162904                                           |
| Aria_transaction_log_syncs                             | 108                                              |
| Binlog_commits                                         | 884378                                           |
| Binlog_group_commits                                   | 884287                                           |
| Binlog_group_commit_trigger_count                      | 0                                                |
| Binlog_group_commit_trigger_lock_wait                  | 0                                                |
| Binlog_group_commit_trigger_timeout                    | 0                                                |
| Binlog_snapshot_file                                   | mysql-bin.000038                                 |
| Binlog_snapshot_position                               | 552835703                                        |
| Binlog_bytes_written                                   | 1626601753                                       |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                                  | 4811                                             |
| Binlog_cache_use                                       | 882274                                           |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                             | 18                                               |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                                  | 2104                                             |
| Busy_time                                              | 0.000000                                         |
| Bytes_received                                         | 8740754817                                       |
| Bytes_sent                                             | 80380675660                                      |
| Compression                                            | OFF                                                                                           |
| Connections                                            | 143465                                           |
| Cpu_time                                               | 0.000000                                         |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                                | 43263                                            |
| Created_tmp_files                                      | 4545                                             |
| Created_tmp_tables                                     | 961351                                                                                         |
| Delete_scan                                            | 2230                                             |
| Empty_queries                                          | 19369816                                         
| Handler_commit                                         | 42120185                                         |
| Handler_delete                                         | 451478                                           |
| Handler_discover                                       | 80                                               |
| Handler_external_lock                                  | 0                                                |
| Handler_icp_attempts                                   | 666402417                                        |
| Handler_icp_match                                      | 666047991                                        |
| Handler_mrr_init                                       | 0                                                |
| Handler_mrr_key_refills                                | 0                                                |
| Handler_mrr_rowid_refills                              | 0                                                |
| Handler_prepare                                        | 2037194                                          |
| Handler_read_first                                     | 1982567                                          |
| Handler_read_key                                       | 209265796                                        |
| Handler_read_last                                      | 37519                                            |
| Handler_read_next                                      | 1432606756                                       |
| Handler_read_prev                                      | 31759933                                         |
| Handler_read_retry                                     | 0                                                |
| Handler_read_rnd                                       | 41884968                                         |
| Handler_read_rnd_deleted                               | 17169                                            |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                                  | 1168367173                                       |
| Handler_rollback                                       | 13                                               |
| Handler_savepoint                                      | 7376                                             |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                             | 0                                                |
| Handler_tmp_delete                                     | 0                                                |
| Handler_tmp_update                                     | 3760231                                          |
| Handler_tmp_write                                      | 108494398                                        |
| Handler_update                                         | 723675                                           |
| Handler_write                                          | 468014                                           |
| Innodb_adaptive_hash_hash_searches                     | 0                                                |
| Innodb_adaptive_hash_non_hash_searches                 | 1124586899                                       |
| Innodb_background_log_sync                             | 39208                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                         |                                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                         | Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210719  4:50:16 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status                       |                                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_incomplete                     | OFF                                              |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                          | 840319                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                          | 13767786496                                      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                         | 45657                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                         | 748044288                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                       | 206518                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                          | 321041                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young                | 12973877                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young                    | 634254                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old                           | 310176                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                         | 1161360                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_lru_flushed                   | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd                      | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                          | 79                                               |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted                  | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests                       | 4634798929                                       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                               | 799144                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                           | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests                      | 12861326                                         |
| Innodb_checkpoint_age                                  | 406077659                                        |
| Innodb_checkpoint_max_age                              | 434155992                                        |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                                     | 55314                                            |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                             | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                              | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                             | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_read                                       | 13094846464                                      |
| Innodb_data_reads                                      | 871143                                           |
| Innodb_data_writes                                     | 1116053                                          |
| Innodb_data_written                                    | 2917482773                                       |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                             | 131349                                           |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                                    | 1077                                             |
| Innodb_deadlocks                                       | 0                                                |
| Innodb_history_list_length                             | 3                                                |
| Innodb_ibuf_discarded_delete_marks                     | 0                                                |
| Innodb_ibuf_discarded_deletes                          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_ibuf_discarded_inserts                          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_ibuf_free_list                                  | 1436                                             |
| Innodb_ibuf_merged_delete_marks                        | 381882                                           |
| Innodb_ibuf_merged_deletes                             | 4726                                             |
| Innodb_ibuf_merged_inserts                             | 39635                                            |
| Innodb_ibuf_merges                                     | 7900                                             |
| Innodb_ibuf_segment_size                               | 1943                                             |
| Innodb_ibuf_size                                       | 506                                              |
| Innodb_log_waits                                       | 0                                                |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                              | 341852                                           |
| Innodb_log_writes                                      | 936910                                           |
| Innodb_lsn_current                                     | 69175355827                                      |
| Innodb_lsn_flushed                                     | 69175354210                                      |
| Innodb_lsn_last_checkpoint                             | 68769278168                                      |
| Innodb_master_thread_active_loops                      | 30283                                            |
| Innodb_master_thread_idle_loops                        | 8926                                             |
| Innodb_max_trx_id                                      | 96623855                                         |
| Innodb_mem_adaptive_hash                               | 0                                                |
| Innodb_mem_dictionary                                  | 211733568                                        |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                                   | 32811                                            |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                           | 0                                                |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                           | 0                                                |
| Innodb_os_log_written                                  | 3097520128                                       |
| Innodb_page_size                                       | 16384                                            |
| Innodb_pages_created                                   | 82283                                            |
| Innodb_pages_read                                      | 799195                                           |
| Innodb_pages_written                                   | 178087                                           |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                                   | 23594                                            |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                               | 291                                              |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                               | 20972                                            |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                                  | 81                                               |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                                    | 451067                                           |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                                   | 466012                                           |
| Innodb_rows_read                                       | 2767518874                                       |
| Innodb_rows_updated                                    | 291502                                           |
| Innodb_system_rows_deleted                             | 0                                                |
| Innodb_system_rows_inserted                            | 0                                                |
| Innodb_system_rows_read                                | 205025                                           |
| Innodb_system_rows_updated                             | 0                                                |
| Innodb_num_open_files                                  | 16144                                            |
| Innodb_secondary_index_triggered_cluster_reads         | 733372971                                                                                 |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                                 | 0                                                |
| Key_blocks_unused                                      | 106026                                           |
| Key_blocks_used                                        | 2073                                             |
| Key_blocks_warm                                        | 2                                                |
| Key_read_requests                                      | 954974                                           |
| Key_reads                                              | 15590                                            |
| Key_write_requests                                     | 25758                                            |
| Key_writes                                             | 7625                                             |
| Last_query_cost                                        | 0.000000                                         |
| Master_gtid_wait_count                                 | 0                                                |
| Master_gtid_wait_time                                  | 0                                                |
| Master_gtid_wait_timeouts                              | 0                                                |
| Max_statement_time_exceeded                            | 0                                                |
| Max_used_connections                                   | 306                                              |
| Memory_used                                            | 1232810768                                       |
| Memory_used_initial                                    | 33626248                                         |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                               | 0                                                |
| Open_files                                             | 238                                              |
| Open_streams                                           | 4                                                |
| Open_table_definitions                                 | 40000                                            |
| Open_tables                                            | 16144                                            |
| Opened_files                                           | 292123                                           |
| Opened_plugin_libraries                                | 0                                                |
| Opened_table_definitions                               | 80968                                            |
| Opened_tables                                          | 288311                                           |
| Opened_views                                           | 1                                                |
| Queries                                                | 41505265                                         |
| Questions                                              | 41505265                                         |
| Rows_read                                              | 2238016094                                       |
| Rows_sent                                              | 363638953                                        |
| Rows_tmp_read                                          | 21299678                                         |
| Select_full_join                                       | 20989                                            |
| Select_full_range_join                                 | 25263                                            |
| Select_range                                           | 19735506                                         |
| Select_range_check                                     | 0                                                |
| Select_scan                                            | 3619795                                                                                       |
| Slow_queries                                           | 91                                               |
| Sort_merge_passes                                      | 875                                              |
| Sort_priority_queue_sorts                              | 210279                                           |
| Sort_range                                             | 4010080                                          |
| Sort_rows                                              | 34727539                                         |
| Sort_scan                                              | 1066118                                          |
| Subquery_cache_hit                                     | 717168                                           |
| Subquery_cache_miss                                    | 1571758                                          |
| Syncs                                                  | 3347                                             |
| Table_locks_immediate                                  | 291843                                           |
| Table_locks_waited                                     | 60                                               |
| Table_open_cache_active_instances                      | 1                                                |
| Table_open_cache_hits                                  | 46645351                                         |
| Table_open_cache_misses                                | 2666806                                          |
| Table_open_cache_overflows                             | 271551                                                                                      |
| Threadpool_idle_threads                                | 0                                                |
| Threadpool_threads                                     | 0                                                |
| Threads_cached                                         | 4                                                |
| Threads_connected                                      | 9                                                |
| Threads_created                                        | 19305                                            |
| Threads_running                                        | 1                                                | Update_scan                                            | 2604                                             |
| Uptime                                                 | 39677
```

My.cnf

```
[server]
binlog_format=mixed
query_cache_size       = 0
query_cache_type       = 0
query_cache_limit      = 8M
max_connections           = 450
wait_timeout              = 120
interactive_timeout       = 19200
tmp_table_size            = 24M
max_heap_table_size       = 24M
thread_cache_size         = 4
max_allowed_packet = 256M
table_open_cache                        = 20000
table_definition_cache                  = 40000
open_files_limit                        = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout  = 50
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size   = 18G
innodb_log_buffer_size    = 256M
innodb_log_file_size      = 512M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit          = 2
innodb_flush_method                     = O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown     = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup      = ON
innodb_write_io_threads                 = 16
analyze_sample_percentage               = 0
optimizer_search_depth=                 = 0
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? We are experiencing the same thing after upgrading from 10.4, so it seems to be a 10.5 thing. I opened https://jira.mariadb.org/projects/MDEV/issues/MDEV-28518 for it so if you still experience the issue you can chime in there. We use ZFS as underlying storage, but don't see abnormal usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running out of memory dropping the innodb buffer pool size can be done. Looking at `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` vs `Innodb_buffer_pool_reads` shows a very high cache ration. As swap/crashing is the alternate reducing this is recommended.

Note mysqldump significantly trashes both innodb buffer pool and table cache. Maybe the swapping can explain the increase it time so resolve that first.

[optimizer_search_depth=0](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#optimizer_search_depth) is an autosize value and the default. Hopefully resolving the table cache reduces the statistics time without further intervention.

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2, recommend going back to the default for safety. Recommend looking at [innodb_io_capacity](https://mysqlonarm.github.io/tune-your-io-workload/) and related system variable that correspond to your storage hardware.

`Threads_created`/ `Uptime` is ~0.5, so you are creating a new thread every 2 seconds. Increase `thread_cache_size` so this ration reduces to 1/minute or more. A few extra threads around isn't a major resource consumption.

`Opened_tables` / `Uptime` and `Opened_table_definitions` / `Uptime` still looks high, however if you raised these significantly into to the uptime maybe those ratios aren't current. Look at increasing these along with the [systemd open file limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#configuring-the-open-files-limit) next restart.

query_cache looks odd in the status when you've disabled it in the settings.

`Rows_read` vs `Rows_send` and `Queries` may indicate that there is scope for improving the indexing of some of the tables. Look at reducing the [long_query_time](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#long_query_time), setting [log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-extended-statistics/#log_slow_verbosity).

`Created_tmp_disk_tables` / `Uptime` ~ 1 indicating that potentially better queries/index are needed.